# Un-evaluated variables in Stack Exchange mail

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, email

Today I received a mail about the public beta release of Coffee Stack Exchange. In the footer I noticed 3 un-evaluated variables:

1. `$SiteNameLong`
2. `$SiteName`
3. `$BaseWebsiteAddress`

The full contents of the footer containing the errors:

> Questions? Comments? Let us know on our [feedback site](http://meta.stackexchange.com). If you no longer want to receive
>   mail from $SiteNameLong, [unsubscribe from all $SiteName emails][7]
>   with a single click.
>
> Stack Exchange, Inc. 110 William St, 28th Floor, NY NY 10038 <3
>
> [7]:
>   http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/unsubscribe/*scrambled url data*
>
> [8]: $BaseWebsiteAddress

Comment: Confirmed - but note that the variables are substituted correctly in the text/html part, just not in the text/plain part.

Comment: I am reading the whole message as text/plain. But yes, variables in the text body are substituted correctly.

Comment: It's a multipart email - there's a text part (MIME type text/plain) and a HTML part (MIME type text/html). For some reason, the footer in the HTML part had the substitutions processed properly, while the footer in the plain text part didn't.

Comment: Aha, I understand now.

Comment: The [*Coffee* site](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A fix just rolled out, though the build rev `1.0.1234.5678` hasn't been incremented. Mysterious...

Comment: Hmm? What a beautiful build rev no.! :)