# Allow moderators to edit sections of privilege help center pages

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, moderators, help-center, moderator-abilities

This question is inspired by the recent public reveal of the [Stack Overflow Question Close Reasons - Definitions and Guidance](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417476/question-close-reasons-definitions-and-guidance). Briefly, the Q&A provides really useful community-specific guidance on what close vote reasons should be used for what problem.

TheFungusAmungus [commented](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417476/question-close-reasons-definitions-and-guidance#comment904999_417476):

> Can this be added to the flag posts privilege wiki?

V2Blast [replied](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417476/question-close-reasons-definitions-and-guidance#comment905009_417476):

> The help pages for each privilege are identical network-wide, so I don't think they can be customized for a specific site. (Even if it were possible, creating a site-specific override of a help center page's text would mean that the site-specific version couldn't be automatically updated anytime the text changed in the network-wide version of that help page.)

That's fair, but it wouldn't be as big of a problem if community moderators were able to edit each site's privilege pages.

In [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/249755/730130) Tim Post noted:

> [Making additional pages in the help center mod-editable] ... is unlikely to happen, but not impossible

I think that `help/privileges/flag-posts`, `help/privileges/close-questions` and `help/closed-questions` are particularly ripe for community-specific guidance.

#### So how about allowing moderators to edit these pages, either totally, like `help/on-topic` or particular short sections like `help/tour`?

---

### [image]

Comment: "it wouldn't be as big of a problem if community moderators were able to edit each site's privilege pages." I thought that was how it did work when a page was customized (but I could be wrong). But the fact is, mods don't read the help center :p

Comment: Certainly would make sense to consider much broader editing abilities, but reading through the meta history, it seems like the company is worried about being able to make updates without having to change *every single one* manually. It seems like `help/dont-ask` would be a great one to be able to edit.

Comment: There's a lot about our help center page policy that I'm not suuuuuper happy with. Things like "we don't want to make updates that will override custom content" is great - if we actually did that... but many of our help pages are very old and we just don't update them often enough to be so worried about it. I'd really like to see us open up more of these pages to customization or find a way to give a site-specific section that can be edited with additional details for that site. That said, I can't make any promises but I know it's something we've discussed at times.

Comment: Related: [What parts of the help center can site moderators edit?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/259914/335251) (Also, note that `/help/closed-questions` isn't a privilege help page – it's just a regular help center page that CMs could set to be moderator-editable if we wanted...)

Comment: @Catija maybe allow revisions by moderators that other sites can use, like community specific close reasons that can be activated. Although, I want SE to actually lay the law of the land for all the communities, so that experiences don't diverge too much from one site to the other.