# What is the purpose of limiting access to edit help center pages?

Tags: feature-request, support, moderator-tools, help-center, localization

As far as I know the number of help center pages available to edit by moderators is very limited: [What parts of the help center can site moderators edit?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/259914/339911)

Moreover, I (as a moderator of ruSO) can't confirm that the answer for the question just mentioned is still correct.

I found some questions like this [Allow moderators to edit sections of privilege help center pages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/377955/339911) that asked for ability to edit more pages.

But I'm curious in general things, what's the reason behind that? Why so strict restrictions are needed that prevents edit of help pages by local site's moderators?

Probably it's just a way to make help pages consistent across all SE sites. Unfortunately this doesn't work for non-English sites, because as the first step all help pages on such sites should be translated.

Could we just made all help pages editable by site moderators, possibly with approval from another mods like it done for revision redaction?

Answer (score 4):

It's so that when a Help page is updated, those changes can be pushed to as many sites as possible. Otherwise, moderators on each site (or staff, I suppose) would have to make the changes individually.

You make a good case for localized mods being able to edit most or all of the Help pages, but there's no need to build tooling for that. You can just ask a CM for permission to edit those pages. Having to go through a CM also ensures that moderators know they'll have to update the page manually and makes sure the request isn't better handled by updating the page for everyone.

Comment: I'm not sure how the ability to edit help page may prevent it update globally by force-pushing updates. Regarding CM - that's the long way to ask CM for something, especially for non-English communities. I don't even know do we have CM or not, in particular ofter the recent layoffs.

Comment: They can't globally update custom pages because that would wipe out any changes made by site mods. As for asking a CM, I guess you would have to translate a summary to English if it's part of a longer discussion (e.g. on your meta). It's a hassle, but hardly an obstacle.

Comment: As far as I see, every editable page has its own history, so no wiping out will occur. After the force-pushing page content could be relatively easily updated by mods to reflect site-specific nuances.